# Java won't import java.awt.Rectangle

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I'm trying to create a simple rectangle that will initialize the values x = 10, y = 15, width = 35 and height = 50, but it's giving me an error:

```
"The import java.awt.Rectangle conflicts with a type defined in the same file"
```

How do i fix this?

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Rectangle 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Rectangle myRect = new Rectangle(10, 15, 35, 50);
    }
}
```

I'm using Eclipse.

Comment: The error message cannot be more clear.

Comment: Please *read the error message* before just mindlessly posting here. I know sometimes error messages can be a little cryptic, but in this case, It's abundantly clear what the problem is. If you still can't understand it, just Google it. `import conflicts with a type defined in the same file` got me dozens of results with the exact some problem and solution.

Comment: I started learning Java today..

Comment: @Traptor Okay, Lesson 1: Google. Learn to use it. 95% of your questions have been asked and answered before. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

Rename your class to something other than `Rectangle` so that Java's own `java.awt.Rectangle` can be used

Comment: Ohh I can't believe I didn't notice that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that you are trying to import a class with the name `Rectangle`, but that will cause a conflict of names with your own class `Rectangle`.

**What can you do?**

1. Rename your class, for example, to `MyRectangle`.
2. *Not recommended*: You can use `java.awt.Rectangle` directly in your code:

   java.awt.Rectangle myRect = new java.awt.Rectangle(10, 15, 35, 50);